# SizeParamIndex for stracture fields?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I wanted to know if we have a marshaling attribute for arrays being a part of a structure with their size stored in another field of the same structure.
For example:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct InetFirewallAcBinaries
    {
        public uint Count;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] public IntPtr[] Binaries;
    }
```

Do we have anything like that?

thanks

Comment: No, there's nothing like that.  Google "pinvoke variable length struct", top hits are all SO posts.

Comment: Well we have it for arguments of a method and yet it is not very known. I thought that we may have it for fields as well.